# Drupal 7 : Tons of HTTP requests from Media Vimeo module

Tags: media

I am using the [Media](https://www.drupal.org/project/media) module

And two of its sub-modules - [YouTube](https://www.drupal.org/project/media_youtube) and [Vimeo](https://www.drupal.org/project/media_vimeo)

As a result - front end page for some reason sends 4 HTTP requests for each Vimeo video on the page and they totally slow down page loading - http://snag.gy/dKEjv.jpg

**Question :**

If there is somebody familiar with these modules or with Vimeo API - could you explain what are these requests for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those HTTP requests look like (slightly broken) video analytics tracking requests via the service [conviva](http://www.conviva.com/insights-overview/).

It might be possible to [opt-out of conviva with Vimeo](http://vimeo.com/forums/feature_requests/topic:113923)

See also [Make Vimeo Faster - Opt Out of Conviva](http://vimeo.com/forums/topic:116104)

Comment: thanks for reply, although i already tried previous version of this module and it seems to be working fine, dunno whether it has other bugs and i did not check what is the difference between them but as from my perspective this one works normally for now - 7.x-1.0-beta5 - https://drupal.org/node/1503252